# Spring Webflow - Access conversation-scoped item in Converter class

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm trying to implement a Converter in Spring 3 (using Webflow). The scenario is that I'm showing a form:select tag with a list of Competition objects. On submission of the form I want the Converter to take the id from the selected element of the list, then determine the correct element of the list and return that to my model.

I'd like to do this by accessing the list of objects supplied to the form:select tag in my converter, allowing me to loop through these and select the correct one.

I wanted to do this by making my Converter object implement ApplicationContextAware and extract the list from there, but every time my converter is run the context is null. On start-up, however, a breakpoint in the setApplicationContext method tells me it is being injected, but it's gone by the time I want to use it.

My questions are:

1) Am I going about this in the right way, or have I missed something obvious?
2) Assuming I've not missed something, what do I need to do to get the context into my converter?

All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my business need on this, but not in the fashion I described above. Instead of accessing the list of objects, I now pass my DAO object into the Converter (by passing it into the ConversionService and passing it as a constructor argument to to the Converter itself), and use the DAO to retrieve the object from the database.

This is not an ideal solution, as it hit the D/B more often than I'd like, but it works.